# div class works with css but span class doesn't?

Tags: css, html

I've tried marking up a letter, and I'm wondering why when I use span class, css is not implemented (date doesn't move to the left), but when I use div class, css is implemented. (date moves to the left). I assumed both should work but one is a block level element and the other is an inline. I changed this line:

```
<div class="receiver-column"> 20 January 2016 </div>
```

to

```
<span class="receiver-column">20 January 2016 </span>
```

Heres the html code:

```css
body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.receiver-column {
  text-align: right;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

p,
ul,
ol,
dl,
address {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

p,
li,
dd,
dt,
address {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<p class="receiver-column"><strong>Dr. Eleanor Gaye </strong> Awesome Science faculty <br> University of Awesome <br> Bobtown, CA 99999, <br> USA <br>
  <strong>Tel</strong>: 123-456-7890 <br>
  <strong>Email</strong>: no_reply@example.com </p>

<div class="receiver-column"> 20 January 2016 </div>
```

Comment: `one is a block level element and the other is an inline` a yup

Comment: Currently everything is aligned right, as the `.receiver-column` class is applied both to the `p` and  the `div` element (both block elements). You have no spans in your HTML code. So what's the problem?

Comment: if i change div to span, it won't work.

Comment: yes, because `span` is an inline element, as you already wrote in the question. So just use the DIV, as you do already. What's the question?

Comment: I understand the effect of inline and block in html, but not how that relates to implementing css.

Comment: If you want your span to be a block than use `.receiver-column {display: block; text-align: right;}`, and both would be rendered same way.

Answer (score 3):

A `span`element is inline, and therefore it is only as wide as its content (i.e. typically the text it contains). Now if you apply `text-align: right` to it, even if the text *is* aligned right, that would be only within the span's width, which is only as wide as its content. So that simply won't make a difference.

Therefore, if you want to use text alignment, use a block element like `div`, `p` , `h1`, `h2`, `h3` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Span is by default display: inline element while Div is Display : block